# Trying to do a simple calculation and having trouble

Tags: c#

```
decimal classAPrice, classBPrice, classCPrice, classASales, classBSales, classCSales, classARevenue, classBRevenue, classCRevenue, allRevenue;
decimal classAPrice = 15.75m, classBPrice = 12.25m, classCPrice = 9.5m;
Label revenueA.Show((decimal classAPrice * decimal classASales).ToString());
```

That's what I currently have, and it's saying things like

> Form1 already has a definition for classAPrice.

Comment: That's because you are declaring `classAPrice` twice.

Comment: OMG! I am unable to understand your code, specially last line.

Comment: Declaring multiple variables on a single line in C# is generally discouraged. But honestly, it looks like you should go and take a basic C# tutorial before asking questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `decimal` keyword in your equation, you are declaring the variable. You only need to declare the variable once, to specify its type, then you can use it like so:

```
classAPrice * classASales
```

You can do the same thing for the `Label`, you have declared it somewhere else, now simply do:

```
revenueA.Show(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the same variable twice. Remove the second `"decimal"` and separate the calculations with `";"` instead of `","`

[image]

Change this:

```
Label revenueA.Show((decimal classAPrice * decimal classASales).ToString());
```

to this:

```
Label revenueA.Show((classAPrice * classASales).ToString());
```

and assign a value to `classASales` before you use it. `(classASales = somevalue)`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `classAPrice` and `classASales` 3 separate times.

Once in your variable declerations:

```
decimal classCPrice, classASales, classBSales, classCSales, classARevenue, classBRevenue, classCRevenue, allRevenue;
```

And in your second line where you initialize the variables

```
decimal classAPrice = 15.75m, classBPrice = 12.25m, classCPrice = 9.5m;
```

And finally in the calculations

```
Label revenueA.Show((decimal classAPrice * decimal classASales).ToString());`
```

Just remove the keyword `decimal` from the second and third lines so in all your code should look like this:

```
decimal classAPrice, classBPrice, classCPrice, classASales, classBSales, classCSales, classARevenue, classBRevenue, classCRevenue, allRevenue;
classAPrice = 15.75m, classBPrice = 12.25m, classCPrice = 9.5m;
Label revenueA.Show((classAPrice * classASales).ToString());
```

Also I would advise to restructure your code as this could become hard to read if you continue on structuring your code like this.

**Example:**

Instead of:

```
decimal classAPrice, classBPrice, classCPrice, classASales, classBSales, classCSales, classARevenue
```

You can make it cleaner by separating each declaration into its own unit:

```
decimal classAPrice; 
decimal classBPrice; 
decimal classCPrice; 
decimal classASales; 
decimal classBSales;
decimal classCSales; 
decimal classARevenue;
```

If you follow this formatting or use another you will find that your code will be much easier to not only read but more importantly understand.

Happy coding! :)